# Chown Not Responding as I expected

Tags: permissions, mysql, chown

I recently changed the permission of mysql, `/var/lib/mysql` so I could save a database in it manually (was only option currently, instead of importing it the proper way). To do so, I had to change the permissions from username: MySQL Server and group: mysql. When I tried to change it back I got this error: `chown: invalid user: ‘MySQL’`... Where to now?

Comment: Did you use upper case letters? the username needs to be all lower-case, like `mysql`

Comment: Yeah! User-name was mysql. I thought it would be the same as that under the directories properties > permissions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The username is probably `mysql`, not "MySQL Server" or "MySQL". Remember, everything in Linux is case sensitive.

You can also find out the exact username by running `grep -i mysql /etc/passwd` and take a look at the first word, that's the username.

Answer (score 0):

Try this to set back the permission:

```
sudo chown mysql:mysql /var/lib/mysql
```

You can check if the mysql user is available on your system with the command:

```
id mysql
```

it should response something like this:

```
uid=107(mysql) gid=111(mysql) groups=111(mysql)
```

Comment: Thanks, much appreciated. I normally up vote all reasonable answers but I don’t have enough rep, my apologises.

Comment: @Smillification you don't need rep to up vote, but no problem^^

Comment: You do... need 15 XD

Comment: @Smillification really? didn't know that.. never mind =)